# Unable to use the web view of Golang PPROF in AWS ec2 server

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-ec2

I have backend application developed in Golang. We are facing memory leak issues, so I thought to use the pprof profiling tool. I could access the tool in interactive mode in terminal, but unable to view the webview.

Getting this error :

```
exec: "sensible-browser": executable file not found in $PATH
```

We are using AWS ec2 instance for our application. Please find the attachment to see the error. Please help me, Thanks in Advance.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message is basically saying that it is unable to find a default browser to view your pprof data.

Depending on where you are executing your pprof commands (cannot tell from the screenshot) you can either:

1. set the default browser on a machine that can have one. See: https://askubuntu.com/a/16626/38168 for details but it boils down to having env variable `BROWSER` set:

```
export BROWSER=/usr/bin/firefox
```

or,

2. if you're executing commands on some remote shell - where you cannot have a browser, you can just generate a pprof dump (e.g. `cpu.prof`) and then retrieve it to your desktop and view it in browser with a command:

```
go tool pprof -http=:8081 cpu.prof
```